# Laravel SPA returning a 419 when I logout and want to login back again

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios

Laravel SPA returning is returning an 419 when I logout and want to login back again. This problem wont ocure when I refresh the page. At first I had it running over a different route api/login but changed this to admin/login perhaps I forgot to change something? I have seen that this issue is caused by a expired CRSF token?

**loginController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }

    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        $customMessages = [
            'email.required' => 'validation.required',
            'password.required' => 'validation.required',
        ];

        $rules =[
            'email' => ['required', 'email'],
            'password' => ['required'],
        ];
 
        return Validator::make($data, $rules, $customMessages);
    }

    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        if ($this->validator($request->all())->fails()) {
            $errors = $this->validator($request->all())->errors()->getMessages();            
            $clientErrors = [];

            foreach ($errors as $key => $value) {
                $clientErrors[$key] = $value[0];
            }

            return $this->sendError( 'Validation error', $clientErrors, 201);
        } else {
 
            $credentials = [
                'email' => $request->email,
                'password' => $request->password,
            ];

            $user = User::where('email', $request->email)->firstOrFail();

            if (auth()->attempt($credentials)) {

               $token = $user->createToken($request->device_name)->plainTextToken;

               $response = [
                    'user' => $user,
                    'access_token' => $token,
                    'token_type' => 'Bearer',
                    'tokendata' =>$request->user()->tokens()
                ];

                return $this->sendResponse( 'Login successfully', $response, 200);
            } else {          
                $clientErrors = [
                    "title" => "auth.no_match_found",
                    "msg" => "auth.not_matching_credentials"
                ];

                return $this->sendError('Invalid login', $clientErrors, 201);        
            }
        }
    }

    public function logout(Request $request)
    {
        if (!empty($request->user())) {
            $request->user()->tokens()->delete();
            $request->session()->invalidate();
            $request->session()->regenerateToken();
        }
    }
}
```

**config/cors.php**

```
'paths' => [
    'api/*',
    'auth/*',
    'admin/*',
    '/login',
    '/logout',
    '/sanctum/csrf-cookie'
],

'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

'allowed_origins' => ['*'],

'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

'exposed_headers' => [],

'max_age' => 0,

'supports_credentials' => true,
```

**config/auth.php**

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'sanctum',
        'provider' => 'users',
        'hash' => false,
    ],
],
```

**bootstrap.js**

```
window.axios = require('axios');
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
window.axios.defaults.baseURL = process.env.MIX_APP_URL;

window.axios.defaults.headers.common = {
   'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
   'Content-Type': 'application/json',
   'Accept': 'application/json'
};

let token = document.head.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]');

if (token) {
    window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = token.content;
} else {
    console.error('CSRF token not found: https://laravel.com/docs/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token');
}
```

**ComponentLogin.vue**

```
const data = {
            email : this.fields.email,
            password : this.fields.password
        }
await axios.get('/sanctum/csrf-cookie');
const response = await axios.post('auth/login', data)
```

Answer (score 0):

To me seems like a route's cache problem.

but what about using the `guard` to logout .

**loginController.php**

```php
public function logout(Request $request)
{
    $this->guard()->logout();       
}
```

Comment: Already tried this but this will throw a ```Method Illuminate\Auth\RequestGuard::logout does not exist.``` error

Comment: Can you share your whole LoginController's file?

Comment: sure no problem

Comment: Really weird the that method doesn't exist, try with ``Auth::logout();`` instead.